# Manually entering medians as centroids of K-means, in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a 2d np.array with 3 columns, coming from 4 categories of registrations. I want to implement K-means on this 3-columns np array to test if it can automatically be clustered to 4 3-dimensional good-enough clusters. So I initiate my centroids from the medians of the real categories (3 medians * 4 categories i want to cluster), and not from means because they all come from a non-parametric distribution. I scaled my data and created an np.array of medians (3*4) but i get this error:

```
clean=[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]

init_medians=np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]])
model = KMeans(n_clusters=4, max_iter=300, init=init_medians)
model.fit(clean)
```

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I have tried changing the array to np array, stack etc but it seems I cannot enter 3 medians per cluster. I think K-means can cluster on 3-dimensional spaces right?

It worked when i intiated the centroids with 4 single values but this is not what I want. The error is caused by the array i input to the init= . Is there a problem on my logic or K- means knowledge or some syntax problem?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART 1:**

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

This is a pure `numpy` error and it appears because you have forgotten to use **parentheses** () in order to define the numpy array.

---

**PART 2:**

**First of all, in the `init_medians` you pass 4 lists but they did not have the same dimensions. The last list has 4 elements (i.e. `[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04]`) instead of 3 in order to represent the cluster medians.**

Second, the KMeans's `init` argument expects as input a ndarray of shape (n_clusters, n_features).
In your case, this should be a (4, 3) numpy array like the following:

```
init_medians=np.array( [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]] )
model = KMeans(n_clusters=4, max_iter=300, init=init_medians)
model.fit(clean)
```

---

**PART 3:**
**The data matrix X should be a numpy array not list of lists.**

The full code:

```
clean=np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]])

init_medians=np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]])
model = KMeans(n_clusters=4, max_iter=300, init=init_medians)
model.fit(clean)
```

Comment: thank you very much. the last part was a typo, because i simplified my code for you. i also fixed the parentheses problem but i now get: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: makaros dear thank you a lot. i tried and it woks like a charm :) solved!

Answer (score 0):

Did you not simply forget to put brackets around np.array?

```
init_medians=np.array([...])
```

Comment: thank you, it is not like that. I added the parentheses as you said but there is no difference.

Comment: Perhaps provide a reproducible code then (with variables defined) to help us?

Comment: thank you again for your help. I updated the code and the description to a simplified and reproducible version

Comment: Are you able to also provide an example of the variable 'clean'? Also you should edit in the brackets around the array function call.

Comment: i did this also! :)